# How to use toString(16) in javascript to get byte written in two character

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm using this function to convert byte array to hex string:

```
function toHexString(bytes)
 {
  return bytes.map(function (byte)
   {
    return (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)
   }).join('')
 }
```

The issue is that function write bytes <=15 (F in hex) in one character for example:

- 10 --> A (but i want to write 0A)

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If byte is below 16, `toString(16)` returns one character, so you have to prepend the desired zero. Else if byte is 16 or more, you may use your original code, because `toString(16)` returns two characters.

```
if (byte < 16)
    return '0' + byte.toString(16);
else
    ...
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add some explanation to your code: why does it works? What should it do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
function toHexString(bytes) {
    var result = bytes.map(function (byte) {
    if(byte>15)
        return (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)
    else
        return '0'+(byte & 0xFF).toString(16)
     }).join('')
}
```

Just check the byte value if it's greater than 15 if not add `0` to the result.

Comment: That works just when I've one byte to convert not for byte array but I solve this like so:  
        if(byte>15)    return (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)
        else return '0'+(byte & 0xFF).toString(16)